# Google chrome extension - input validation not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension the following statement,

```
<input type="text" id="sample" required>
```

does not validate the text field. Meaning if I submit the form with empty fields, the chrome extension doesn't specify "Please fill out this field".

I added the jquery statement, `$("input").prop('required',true);` as well, but yet it doesn't work. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

You can Try this

Some Browser in problem same as like than when ever we use directly required keyword`

> `<input type="text" id="sample" required="required">`

or

You can create text box using Bootstrap

@Html.TextBox("sample", null, new { @class = "input-xlarge", type = "text", required = "required" })

you can put into jquery

> `new { required = sample.Empty}`